# NodeJS + Mongoose PATCH method with findByIdAndUpdate return nothing even new: true in option is set

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm using Mongoose 5.8.6 and I cannot receive modified model (in response is nothing) in request response. Saving is OK, but only response is empty. I added { new: true } option and still the same. Anyone knows where is the problem?

```
this.router.patch(this.path + '/:id', this.modifyConfiguration)

private modifyConfiguration = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    if (!req.body || (!req.body.name && !req.body.config) || !req.params.id) {
        return res.status(400).json({ message: 'Incorrect request content' });
    }

    await Configuration.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body, { new: true }, async (err, item) => {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(400).json({ message: err.message });
        } else {
            return res.status(204).json(item);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: This should work. but you dont need async in callback function right?

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be like this

```
this.router.patch(this.path + '/:id', this.modifyConfiguration)
private modifyConfiguration = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    try {
        if (!req.body || (!req.body.name && !req.body.config) || !req.params.id) {
            return res.status(400).json({ message: 'Incorrect request content' });
        }

        const item = await Configuration.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body, { new: true });

        return res.status(204).json(item);
    } catch (error) {
        return res.status(400).json({ message: error.message });

    }
}
```